# Why does jquery not respond accordingly to my conditions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my tablerows to have the class 'clickable' only if edit mode is turned on. With element inspect I can see that this works. It succesfully removes the 'clickable' class if I turn off edit mode.

If a table row has the class clickable it will click it's checkbox upon clicking the table row.
 This works too, however when I turn off edit mode, I'm still able to click tablerows and by doing so, also check the checkbox. 

If you can see something that I've overlooked please let me know.

```
    function clickableTableRow(isClickable) { 
        if (isClickable) {
            $(tableBody).find('tr').each(function () {
                $(this).addClass("clickable"); 
                $(this).click(function () {
                    $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').click(); 
                });
            })
        } else {
            $(tableBody).find('tr').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass("checked").removeClass("clickable");
                $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
            })
        }
    }
```

So to clarify, in element inspect I can see that it does all as it should, so I think the problem lays in the function where I make a checkbox click upon clicking on a tablerow

Comment: Can I get to see a screenshot for the same or a working fiddle , question is litle confusing for me , Say you have a table with 3 rows and a checkbox attached to each row, when click of tr anywhere in the row, we should select the checkbox ? what does the clickable mode does, does it stop propagation of the event if clickable is false or it calls the function ?

Comment: remove the `click event`. Like: `$(this).off('click');`

Comment: @Roy thanks, this worked. I'm relatively new to javascript and especially jquery, so I didn't know this even was a thing

Comment: @OmarRuder Nice, good luck then!

Comment: You should consider making the checkboxes readonly or disabled. Otherwise the OS controls are going to be active and clickable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.off()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-off-method/)

```
$(this).off('click');
```

> The `off()` Method in **jQuery** is used to remove event handlers attached
>   with the `on()` method -or the `.click()` method. The `off()` method brings a lot of consistency to
>   the API and it replace `unbind()`, `die()` and `undelegate()` methods.

Answer (score -1):

The event handler was still active, using .off() turns it off.
 Adding this line of code tot the else statement solved the issue:

 `$(this).off('click');`